# moveit rviz plugin error

Tags: rviz, moveit, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 14.04 trusty

ros indigo

when i launch:

```
roslaunch clam_moveit_config moveit_rviz.launch
```

i get :

```
[ERROR] [1410332944.683556716]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning' failed to load.  Error: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning with base class type rviz::Display does not exist. Declared types are  rviz/Axes rviz/Camera rviz/DepthCloud rviz/Effort rviz/FluidPressure rviz/Grid rviz/GridCells rviz/Illuminance rviz/Image rviz/InteractiveMarkers rviz/LaserScan rviz/Map rviz/Marker rviz/MarkerArray rviz/Odometry rviz/Path rviz/PointCloud rviz/PointCloud2 rviz/PointStamped rviz/Polygon rviz/Pose rviz/PoseArray rviz/Range rviz/RelativeHumidity rviz/RobotModel rviz/TF rviz/Temperature rviz/WrenchStamped rviz_plugin_tutorials/Imu
```

i need to install something, apt-get install [what?]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192369/moveit-rviz-plugin-error/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

installed some missing "moveit rviz" stuff through synaptic.

---

Originally posted by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) with karma: 259 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alubitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25835/alubitz/) on 2016-02-03**:
ever thought of posting which?

**Comment by [alubitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25835/alubitz/) on 2016-02-03**:
sudo apt-get install ros--moveit-ros-visualization

**Comment by [GPrathap](https://answers.ros.org/users/31593/gprathap/) on 2018-08-13**:
Yeah after installing ( ros--moveit-ros-visualization) resolved issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Kinetic, you may install:

> sudo apt-get install
> ros-kinetic-moveit-visual-tools

see also [this](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/issues/85)

---

Originally posted by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) with karma: 277 on 2017-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:
I'm not sure `moveit-visual-tools` is actually related to this question. It's a package by Dave Coleman, but not part of the 'core' MoveIt RViz plugin infrastructure.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-09**:
"moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning" is part of ros--moveit-ros-visualization, as stated before.
You can get a similar message though for `rviz_visual_tools/RvizVisualToolsGui` if `ros-<distro>-rviz-visual-tools` is not installed.